# Threaded Maven builds with sequential Unit Tests?

Tags: testing, maven, junit, maven-surefire-plugin

With Maven 3 it`s possible to build Projects with multiple Threads, like

```
mvn -T 4 clean install
```

Since we have Unit-Tests setting up on a consistent Database (and manipulating the data during execution), we need to make sure, that these Unit Tests are not running in parallel execution. I know that there is a configuration-option for Maven-Surefire-Plugin to execute Tests sequentially or enable parallel execution:

```
<configuration>
   <parallel>classes</parallel>
</configuration>
```

When I leave this configuration empty Tests should be executed sequentially, right? But is execution still sequentially when calling the Build with multiple Maven-Threads (-T) like above?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand and from the [documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/MAVEN/parallel-builds-in-maven-3.html), parallel build runs `modules` in parallel and not the `goals` within each module.   That being the case, the unit tests in a module will run sequentially unless configured in surefire to run in parallel.

Comment: Thx for your response. But what means "...runs modules in parallel"? Isn't it neccessary to execute a goal on each module (in parallel) to "run a module"?

Comment: @heinkunibert.  Indeed.  That is exactly what maven would do when it runs.

Comment: But if Maven executes goals on seperate modules in parallel the execution of unit-test within a project isn`t sequential anymore, no matter how I configured surefire-plugin. Seems that I can`t take advantage of threaded Maven Builds as long as I want sequential execution of Unit-Tests, right?

Comment: @heinkunibert. a maven module is a separate maven project, and not a part of a project build.  As such, parallel execution is relevant in multi-module projects and not for a single project.

Comment: sorry, when talking of a project I meant a multi-module project for sure ;-).

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for might be [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2286571/does-maven-surefire-plugin-run-tests-using-multiple-threads).  It's about how surefire forks and or runs parallel threads.