# ApplicationContext created in multiple threads when running tests with Maven

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven, junit, liquibase

I have two `persistence-unit`s, which are identical except other uses Hibernate's hbm2ddl `create-drop` and the other uses `validate` and there the database is created by liquiBase.

Now running any of the tests (HSQLDB named in-mem db) from eclipse, they work fine. But running all of them from maven, they brake with strange foreign key violations.

What I think is strange is that I get messages from 4 different threads and for example closing one of the Persistence Units happens while table drops are still written to console.

Why do I get four threads, all with their own ApplicationContexts? I have no `parallel` parameters set for surefire and I'm not using -T switch for maven either.

Edit:

Here's a snippet from the commandline output of Maven

```
Hibernate: drop table PostalCodeDistribution if exists
Hibernate: drop table PublicationAudit if exists
15:21:13.672 [Thread-2] INFO  org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean - Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'TestPU-nocreate'
Hibernate: drop table PostalCodeDistributionAudit if exists
Hibernate: drop table PublicationInvoicing if exists
Hibernate: drop table PostalCodeSubscriberCountAudit if exists
15:21:13.672 [Thread-2] INFO  org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl - HHH000030: Cleaning up connection pool [jdbc:hsqldb:mem:ptptest]
Hibernate: drop table Revision if exists
Hibernate: drop table PriceDate if exists
```

Answer (score -1):

As you probably know, by default, SureFire executes your tests in a different thread ("fork").  See: [Does Maven surefire plugin run tests using multiple threads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2286571/does-maven-surefire-plugin-run-tests-using-multiple-threads)

It is likely that your tests, or some libraries used by your tests, execute asynchronously. You should inspect your tests to verify if this is the case.

Comment: I don't think this really answers the question.

Comment: Well, without further details about the test configuration and application code, what else can anybody offer? @vertti needs to follow up either with logs that include thread names, or more details. Note that nobody else has contributed an answer.

Comment: well, one could offer a description of how JPA persistancecontext-related tests work in spring: what is expected reuse policy of application contexts and what things contribute to it. Is it normal to have four different contexts? Or not? Why?